# google.gson.fromJson where classOfT is generic array

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How deserialize array of generic type with gson.fromJson

```java
public class Cache<T> {

    public void M(String json) {
        JsonArray ja = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(json);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        T[] items = gson.fromJson(ja, ?);
    }
}
```

This not work

```java
Type t = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.getType();
T[] items = gson.fromJson(ja, t);
```

```java
T[] items = gson.fromJson(ja, T[].class);
```

```java
T[] items = gson.fromJson(ja, new T[].getClass());
```

Comment: You probably should post also some example json so people can suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 0);
T[] result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, (Type) array.getClass());
List<T> resultList = Arrays.asList(result);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.